# Blank page when deploy React app on github

Tags: reactjs, github

[image]

{

{
"homepage": "https://NegiRishab.github.io/offline-to-do-app",
"name": "to-do-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": false,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like whatever you are trying to iterate over with toConsumableArray is null and cannot be looped over because of that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable

You might consider adding a null check before trying to iterate, and only call toConsumableArray if the object is not null.

Comment: but when i use npm start app is running fine  but when i deploy this issue comes

Comment: It looks like you are depending on local storage:

const [display, setdisplay] = useState([...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('display'))]);

And the storage may exist on your local machine, but on initial load it would not. So you will need to have a check for the local storage value and only try to parse it if it exists.